# Got a warning from autotools

Tags: c++, autotools

ALL,

I just updated one of my Linux boxes and when I tried to rerun the required tools this is what I got:

```
gor@IgorReinCloud ~/dbhandler $ aclocal
igor@IgorReinCloud ~/dbhandler $ autoconf
configure.ac:52: warning: The macro `GLIB_GNU_GETTEXT' is obsolete.
configure.ac:52: You should run autoupdate.
aclocal.m4:388: GLIB_GNU_GETTEXT is expanded from...
aclocal.m4:488: AM_GLIB_GNU_GETTEXT is expanded from...
configure.ac:52: the top level
configure.ac:52: warning: The macro `AC_TRY_LINK' is obsolete.
configure.ac:52: You should run autoupdate.
./lib/autoconf/general.m4:2920: AC_TRY_LINK is expanded from...
lib/m4sugar/m4sh.m4:692: _AS_IF_ELSE is expanded from...
lib/m4sugar/m4sh.m4:699: AS_IF is expanded from...
./lib/autoconf/general.m4:2249: AC_CACHE_VAL is expanded from...
./lib/autoconf/general.m4:2270: AC_CACHE_CHECK is expanded from...
aclocal.m4:73: GLIB_LC_MESSAGES is expanded from...
aclocal.m4:388: GLIB_GNU_GETTEXT is expanded from...
aclocal.m4:488: AM_GLIB_GNU_GETTEXT is expanded from...
configure.ac:52: the top level
configure.ac:52: warning: The macro `AC_TRY_LINK' is obsolete.
configure.ac:52: You should run autoupdate.
./lib/autoconf/general.m4:2920: AC_TRY_LINK is expanded from...
lib/m4sugar/m4sh.m4:692: _AS_IF_ELSE is expanded from...
lib/m4sugar/m4sh.m4:699: AS_IF is expanded from...
./lib/autoconf/general.m4:2249: AC_CACHE_VAL is expanded from...
./lib/autoconf/general.m4:2270: AC_CACHE_CHECK is expanded from...
lib/m4sugar/m4sh.m4:699: AS_IF is expanded from...
./lib/autoconf/headers.m4:89: _AC_CHECK_HEADER_COMPILE is expanded from...
./lib/autoconf/headers.m4:56: AC_CHECK_HEADER is expanded from...
aclocal.m4:172: GLIB_WITH_NLS is expanded from...
aclocal.m4:388: GLIB_GNU_GETTEXT is expanded from...
aclocal.m4:488: AM_GLIB_GNU_GETTEXT is expanded from...
configure.ac:52: the top level
configure.ac:52: warning: The macro `AC_TRY_LINK' is obsolete.
configure.ac:52: You should run autoupdate.
./lib/autoconf/general.m4:2920: AC_TRY_LINK is expanded from...
lib/m4sugar/m4sh.m4:699: AS_IF is expanded from...
./lib/autoconf/headers.m4:89: _AC_CHECK_HEADER_COMPILE is expanded from...
./lib/autoconf/headers.m4:56: AC_CHECK_HEADER is expanded from...
aclocal.m4:172: GLIB_WITH_NLS is expanded from...
aclocal.m4:388: GLIB_GNU_GETTEXT is expanded from...
aclocal.m4:488: AM_GLIB_GNU_GETTEXT is expanded from...
configure.ac:52: the top level
configure.ac:52: warning: The macro `AC_OUTPUT_COMMANDS' is obsolete.
configure.ac:52: You should run autoupdate.
./lib/autoconf/status.m4:1025: AC_OUTPUT_COMMANDS is expanded from...
aclocal.m4:172: GLIB_WITH_NLS is expanded from...
aclocal.m4:388: GLIB_GNU_GETTEXT is expanded from...
aclocal.m4:488: AM_GLIB_GNU_GETTEXT is expanded from...
configure.ac:52: the top level
configure.ac:61: warning: AC_OUTPUT should be used without arguments.
configure.ac:61: You should run autoupdate.
igor@IgorReinCloud ~/dbhandler $
```

What do I do now?

I got those from [here](https://thoughtbot.com/blog/the-magic-behind-configure-make-make-install).

The problem with this is that if I continue, everything will be built, however when I try to rn the program, it doesn't find the library my program depends on. (I'm building that library myself).

So what can I do to fix those warnings? Or maybe it is possible to somehow run the program?

TIA for any pointers!!

Comment: What does "rerun the required tools" mean?  You are rebuilding a package from source, which is not a part of updating the system for most Linux distributions.  But supposing that you do need to do that for some reason, you are *rebuilding its build system*, too, which is to be avoided whenever possible.  And even worse, you are running the individual autotools directly, instead of using `autoreconf`.

Comment: If you want to build this package from source then the first thing to try is to unpack a fresh copy of the source distribution and `configure; make; make install` without running any of the autotools.

Comment: @JohnBollinger, it is not a distribution yet. I'm developing this program. I needed to run them in in order to pick up new versions of the required system packages.

Comment: @JohnBollinger, sorry didn't see the first post. What I mean is - I was running a very old system - built about 5-6 years ago. Now I had to update it because I needed to install something and it was not available. So in order to continue my development I needed my code to pick new version of autotools so that it will reconfigure and recompile everything correctly. Was I wrong? You also mention running `autoreconf`? Is it all I need in this case? And it will pick up everything I updated?

Comment: I see.  Well, if ever you update the version of the autotools that you are using to maintain a project, then the first thing to do is run `autoreconf --install --force` in the root of the project source tree.  I do recommend doing so, but I can't say for sure whether that will resolve all the diagnostics presently being reported to you.

Comment: Only in exceedingly special cases should you run the individual autotools (`aclocal`, `autoconf`, `automake`, *etc*.) manually.  Instead, run `autoreconf` (usually without any options), and it will figure out which of those tools need to be run, in which order, with which options, at run those for you.

Comment: @JohnBollinger, I ust tried to execute `autoreconf --install --force`, but no difference. I still got the same warnings.

Comment: Ok.  Well, the diagnostics suggest running `autoupdate`.  I'm not much familiar with that particular tool, but it would be worth a try.  However, it does look like you must have made a pretty big Autotools version jump, and I expect that that's going to require some manual editing of your `configure.ac`.  Details are hard to judge from the diagnostics alone.